# How to remove NAs with the conditions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to remove some rows with the condition. Here is my data:

```
df_A <- tribble(
  ~product_name,   ~id,  ~clicks,
        "A",        NA,      1,  
        "A",         4,      1, 
        "A",         3,      1, 
        "B",        NA,      NA, 
        "B",         6,      2, 
        "C",        NA,      3, 
        "C",         5,      NA, 
)
```

For instance, I want to remove the first and sixth rows because product A and C in the `product_name` already have the value in the `id` column. But I want to keep the fourth row because it is my condition that if all rows (except `product_name`) are `NA`, it should remain in the data.

And here is my desired data:

```
df_A <- tribble(
  ~product_name,   ~id,  ~clicks,
       "A",          4,      1, 
       "A",          3,      1, 
       "B",         NA,      NA, 
       "B",          6,      2, 
       "C",          5,      NA, 
)
```

Comment: If you have a row: `"D", NA, 3`, do we keep it?

Comment: If there is a row something like this ```"D", NA, 3```, there should be another row as well like this: ```"D", 5, 3```. So we don't keep the first one. @zx8754

Comment: The condition is not very clear... Just for my understanding. The "deletion" condition is: if id is NA, BUT click is not NA and there is at least another row with the same product name, delete the row. It this what you expect?

Comment: How close is this to your real example, i.e. do you have many more columns or that's it?

Comment: That's correct! @Marco

Comment: Yes, I have many more columns. But they are dependent on the produduct_name, so other rows that we did not remove will already have the same values. @arg0naut91

Comment: Ok now it's clear... I provided an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_A %>%
    group_by(product_name) %>%
    filter(!is.na(id) |
               is.na(id) & is.na(clicks))
```

Comment: I think this answer misses the point where the product name is not duplicated... If you add a line like " "D",        NA,      3, ", with this code it is removed as well... From the comments I understood that's not what you want, because "D" is unique as product name...

Answer (score 3):

you can create a dummy column with your condition and filter that

```
df_A %>%
  mutate(
    not_remove = case_when(
      is.na(id) & is.na(clicks) ~ TRUE,
      is.na(id) ~ FALSE,
      TRUE ~ TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(not_remove) %>%
  select(
    -not_remove
  )
```

Comment: You could put the `case_when` inside the `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `ave`

```
df_A_out <- subset(df_A,!(!!ave(id,product_name,FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x))>0) & is.na(id) & !is.na(clicks)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Then this should be the answer:

```
df_A <- df_A[!((duplicated(df_A$product_name) | duplicated(df_A$product_name, fromLast=TRUE)) & is.na(df_A$id) & !is.na(df_A$clicks)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specific conditions to filter on the NAs, I have used if and for loops.
Hope this helps.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_A)){
  if(!is.na(df_A$product_name[i]) & is.na(df_A$id[i]) & is.na(df_A$clicks[i]))
    df_A[i,]<-df_A[i,]
  else if(is.na(df_A$id[i]))
    df_A<-df_A[-i,]
}
```

Output:
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsRMd.png)